# Setting an attribute for XML document using lxml

Tags: xml, python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to build an XML file in which my main node has some attributes:

```
<cbnp-message:cbnp-message xmlns:cbnp-message="some_value" xmlns="some_value2">
```

I am trying to achieve that using Python3 and lxml library and so far I managed to set *xmlns* parameter for *some_value2*. What I can't do I to set *cnbp-message:cnbp-message* thing (sorry for my lack of proper naming: I am not working with XMLs on daily basis).

What is tricky here and prevents me from hard-coding such informations before creating XML file is that ending tag of aforementioned XML has to end with

```
</cbnp-message:cnbp-message>
```

I would appreciate all ideas and suggestion how to tackle such task.

I already tried creating a node with *cnbp-message:cbnp-message* name, it doesn't work though (raises **ValueError: Invalid tag name** exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't normal attributes; those are [namespace declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl).

This declaration: `xmlns:cbnp-message="some_value"` binds the namespace uri `some_value` to the prefix `cbnp-message`.

This declaration: `xmlns="some_value2"` is a default namespace (since the uri is not bound to a prefix).

What you can do in lxml is use "nsmap" to map prefixes to uris. For default namespaces the prefix should be `None`.

To avoid the "Invalid tag name" exception, you'll also need to use `QName()` to build the qualified name (which is the namespace uri and local name in [Clark Notation](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm) (example: `{some_value}cbnp-message`)).

[See here](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces) for more info on namespaces in lxml.

[See here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) (or the link to James Clark's page above) for more info on namespaces in general.

Example...

```py
from lxml import etree

nsmap = {None: "some_value2", "cbnp-message": "some_value"}

message = etree.Element(etree.QName(nsmap.get("cbnp-message"), "cbnp-message"), nsmap=nsmap)

etree.dump(message)
```

Output...

```xml
<cbnp-message:cbnp-message xmlns:cbnp-message="some_value" xmlns="some_value2"/>
```

Comment: I just solved it using xml.etree but still this looks like it might have helped. Thanks :)